# MySQL Select, unique in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Lets say I have a table with the following rows/values:

[image: [1]]

I need a way to select the values in amount but only once if they're duplicated. So from this example I'd want to select A,B and C the amount once. The SQL result should look like this then:

[image]

Comment: What's the use for the empty entries? Wouldn't simply selecting `distinct` yield better results? Why are there those duplicates at all? This makes me wonder if there's going something wrong already earlier (possibly flawed design?).

Comment: You need more than what you're showing, what is the primary key of the table? And what is your mysql version?

Comment: Have you considered selecting the `name, amount, count(*)`?

Comment: which version of mysql you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LAG() function and compare previous amount with current row amount for name.

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
SELECT t.name
     , CASE WHEN t.amount = t.prev_val THEN '' ELSE amount END amount
FROM (SELECT *
           , LAG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) prev_val
      FROM test) t
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c1af9afcadf2849a85ad045df7ed580

Answer (score 2):

You can handle situation like these with different function depending on what you need:

**Case1 :** If you have same values per name:

```
select distinct name, amount from [table name]
```

**Case2 :** You have duplicates with different values for each name and you want to pick the one with the highest value. Use `min()` if you need the minimum one to show up.

```
select name, max(amount) from [table name] group by 1
```

**Case 3:** The one you need with blanks for the rest of the duplications.

- Row number will create rows based on values in amount and since the values are the same it will create it incrementally and you can then use `IF` to create a new column `where rank_ > 1 then blanks`. This will also cover the case where you would like to select just the minimum value and then have blanks for the rest of the name values

```
    With ranking as (
    
    select 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY AMOUNT) AS RANK_    
     from [table]
    )
    SELECT
    *,
    IF(RANK_ > 1,"",AMOUNT) AS NEW_AMOUNT
    FROM ranking
```

**Case 4:** You need to select maximum and put the other names as blank

- You will just adjust the `order by clause of ROW_NUMBER()` to `DESC`. This will put the rank 1 to the highest amount per name and for the rest, the blank will be filled

```
    With ranking as (
    
    select 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC) AS RANK_
     from [table]
    )
    
    SELECT
    *,
    IF(RANK_ > 1,"",AMOUNT) AS NEW_AMOUNT
    FROM ranking
```

Comment: For case 3 - add `ORDER BY name, amount, rank_`. Without this the rows can be unsuccessfully reordered in outer query.

Comment: @Akina since the values are same the same order by ASC will work fine, but yes if the requirement is to get the max and the rest as blank then order by desc will be needed

Comment: I look at desired output. Obviously OP wants to form grouped output, in this case the row with the value in `amount` needs to be the most upper in a group.

Comment: i have added all the cases

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysql 8 you can use `row_number` for this:

```
with x as (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by name order by amount) rn
  from t
)
select name, case when rn=1 then amount else '' end amount
from x
```

See [example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e976e655ff0625069e4be6d2abbf7f5b)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are missing a really important point:  A SQL table returns an *unordered* set unless there is an explicit `order by`.

The data that you have provides has rows that are exact duplicates.  For this reason, I think the best approach uses `row_number()` *and an `order by` in the outer query*:

```
select name, (case when seqnum = 1 then amount end) as amount
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, amount) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by name, seqnum;
```

Note that MySQL does not require an `order by` argument for `row_number()`.

More commonly, though, you would have some other column (say a date or id) that would be used for ordering.  I should also emphasize that this type of formatting is often handled at the application layer and not in the database.